# Frappe Gantt integration with angular 5

Tags: angular, gantt-chart

I am trying to integrate Frappe Gantt library with Angular 5. This is the offiical doc https://frappe.io/gantt but however i cannot figure a way out as typescript throws an error in the component where it says 'Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.', when i execute :

```
frappeGantt = new Gantt("#gantt", this.tasks);
```

Now frappe.min.js is already imported in my index.html But i need to assign new Gantt Object to frappeGantt. Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.frappeGanttChart = new frappeGantt.default("#ganttChart", this.tasks, {});
```

a default keyword need to be added after frappeGantt. This is beacuse the package exports default class.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve in Angular 10, maybe works to you:

It is necessary to set a flag that allows importing by default even if the module is not exportable by default.

My component looks like this:

```
import Gantt from 'frappe-gantt';
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@ angular / core';


@Component ({
  selector: 'myGantt',
  templateUrl: './gantt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gantt.component.scss'],
})
export class GanttComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild ('gantt') ganttEl: ElementRef;

  gantt;
  tasks = [
    {
      id: 'Task 1',
      name: 'Redesign website',
      start: '2016-12-28',
      end: '2016-12-31',
      progress: 20,
      dependencies: 'Task 2, Task 3',
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit () {
    this.gantt = new Gantt ('# gantt', this.tasks);
  }
}
```

The flag is added to the tsconfig.json file:
`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`